# Handlebars Using @root in Custom Helper

Tags: handlebars.js

I have a scenario where I am trying to access a separate element in my custom helper from within a nested for loop. When I use root outside my for loop I don't have any issues, but I can't seem to use `@root` within my custom helper. I thought maybe `../` would work, but it appears that is only be moving up to the parent element, not a one that is separate

**Here are my two objects:**

```
category //Object being looped through
categoryQuery //Query object being compared to looped values
```

**Here is my view (looping through ID's and then apply selected to the ID attached to categoryQuery:**

```
{{#category}}
   <option value="{{this.categoryId}}"{{selected this.categoryId @root.categoryQuery}}>{{this.categoryName}}</option>
{{/category}}
```

**Preselected value if the values match:**

```
/Preselect option value that is associated with edited record
    hbs.registerHelper('selected', function(option, value){
        if (option === value) {
            return 'selected';
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    });
```

**Updated:**

when adding `console.log('Option : ' + option + ' Value : ' + value);` into the `else` statement of my registered helper, I receive the following, which shows that it isn't an issue that `@root.category` isn't pulling in the value, but it isn't equating correctly.

**For example:**

```
Option : 1 Value : 2
Option : 2 Value : 2
Option : 1 Value : undefined
```

Comment: What are the _types_ of `categoryId` and `categoryQuery`?

Answer (score 0):

I determined that the root cause of the issue was the strictness in the comparison operator. When changed to `==` I was able to correctly identify the ID's that matched